# Data augmentation basic python

Tags: python, function, variables, albumentations

I am a beginner in python programming and was learning how to code a project from YouTube when I got stuck on the following code.

The full code is here: https://github.com/nikhilroxtomar/Retina-Blood-Vessel-Segmentation-using-UNET-in-TensorFlow/blob/main/data.py and the YouTube where it appears is at 24:30 - https://youtu.be/tpbWZVY2dng?t=1470 )

```
from albumentations import HorizontalFlip
def augment_data(images, masks, save_path, augment=True):

  for idx, (x, y) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(images, masks)), total=len(images)):
      """ Extracting names """
      name = x.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]

      """ Reading image and mask """
      x = cv2.imread(x, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      y = imageio.mimread(y)[0]

      if augment == True:
          aug = HorizontalFlip(p=1.0)
          augmented = aug(image=x, mask=y)
          x1 = augmented["image"]
          y1 = augmented["mask"]
```

This part is what I don't understand

```
if augment == True:
      aug = HorizontalFlip(p=1.0)
      augmented = aug(image=x, mask=y)
      x1 = augmented["image"]
      y1 = augmented["mask"]
```

How is *aug* being used to take input parameters of an image? Is *augmented* being used as a dictionary? Can you please explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aug` is instance of [`albumentations.augmentations.transforms.HorizontalFlip`](https://vfdev-5-albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/docs_pytorch_fix/api/augmentations.html#albumentations.augmentations.transforms.HorizontalFlip) class

Then if you look at [the source code](https://vfdev-5-albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/docs_pytorch_fix/_modules/albumentations/augmentations/transforms.html#HorizontalFlip) you will see that it inherits from
[`albumentations.core.transforms_interface.DualTransform`](https://vfdev-5-albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/docs_pytorch_fix/api/core.html#albumentations.core.transforms_interface.DualTransform) class which looking at [the source code](https://vfdev-5-albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/docs_pytorch_fix/_modules/albumentations/core/transforms_interface.html#DualTransform) inherits from [`BasicTransform`](https://vfdev-5-albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/docs_pytorch_fix/_modules/albumentations/core/transforms_interface.html#BasicTransform) class.

Looking at the `BasicTransform` class you can see it implements `__call__()` method. It takes variable number of keyword arguments `**kwargs` and after some processing returns `kwargs` (i.e. when you call `aug()`). `kwargs` is a dict with arguments you pass. In your case the keys are `image` and `mask`.

As a side note, instead of  `if augment == True:` it should be just  `if augment:`

Answer (score 1):

`aug` is a variable that is assigned to a function object

Square brackets means the object has implmented `__getitem__()` Python magic method. It could be a dict, but doesn't need to be

Comment: I printed the type of _augmented_ and it was a dictionary. Buran has explained it well and since the class has **__call__ method**, the instance _aug_ behaves like a function and can be called like one too